# vaadin embed in div, how to pass query string

Tags: vaadin

I'm trying to embed my vaadin app into a jsp file, this for the reason I want to do some basic  SEO stuff in there.

Unfortunately, my vaadin app uses a request/parameter handler which is not called with my parameters when I embed the div into the jsp page.

Is there a simple way to pass the query string to the vaadin servlet? I was thinking of something like {appUri:'de'<%=request.getQueryString()%>. But I'm not sure if this is the proper way.

Any proper solution is appreciated :)

Thank you so much.

p.s. I guess iframe would do it, but I would like the div version if possible.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter what you are doing to start your vaadin app.

Just modify your main application to have:

```
public class SomeVaadinApplication extends Application implements HttpServletRequestListener
```

Then in the onRequestStart method:

```
@Override
public void onRequestStart(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

     String someParameter = request.getParameter("SomeParameter");
     //Do something with parameter
}
```

Comment: As you can read above I'm using those listeners. They seem not to be called when embedding the app as a DIV.

Comment: It has to be something in your web.xml. Please post your web.xml. We tried iframes and didn't have any luck getting it to work

Comment: I got it to work with iframe, but I have to use a JSP or the like to pass the request parameters to the iframe.